# ssas cube less data when do mdx query

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I'm quite new in SSAS.I created a cube. I processed the cube.I have less data in the cube than I have in the fact table. when I  do a query mdx i have less data when i query by sql.

```
  SELECT  NON EMPTY { ([Dim Booking].[Booking].[Booking].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION  ON ROWS
  ,NON EMPTY {[Dim Booking Date].[Booking Date].[Booking Date ].ALLMEMBERS} ON COLUMNS
 FROM [cube]
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please make sure that your `default measure` (selected if no measure mentioned in query) filled with data for all intersections of `Booking` and `Booking Date` dimensions, because NON EMPTY is used on both axis. Which means if measure is empty -- it's hidden on the result set. Add data or remove NON EMPTY to see everything. Or add here an image of present in SQL, but missing in MDX members.

Comment: Maybe you have facts with missing dimensions and that's why you lose rows